# Irrevocable Trust- Adding A Beneficiary

Tags: united-states, trusts

In the USA, an irrevocable trust is set up and funded for individual #1. Can an additional beneficiary be added later by the original donor? I am trying to understand how much flexibility irrevocable trusts have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a legal issue, not a money matter. law.SE seems a possible site where this can be migrated.

Comment: I've two other questions answered here about irrevocable trusts along similar lines. I'm open to moving to where ever, but I fail to see what the difference is. Trusts are definitely fall into the category both personal finance and/or money.